# Bootstrap 4 offset from center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a col thats in the center of the page from that col i want another with a little offset from it but this influence the center.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsumus</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 offset-1">test</div>
    </div>
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTEuP.png
How can i do this in boostrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you want the block where the list resides to be always horizontally centered?

First, you want the offset block to have `col-3`, and the offset is `offset-1`. That's totally 4 columns. So if you want the list block to be centered, there has to be 4 columns block on its left as well. And hence the list block should take 4 columns, i.e., `col-4`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 ml-auto">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsumus</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 offset-1">test</div>
</div>
```

[image]

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/91196/